# using _.each to find object in an array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array which looks looks like this -

```
     list = [{"doc":{"id": "123", "name":"abc"}}, {"doc":{"id": "345", "name":"xyz"}},{"doc":{"id": "123", "name":"str"}}]
```

How can I use the _.each method to retrieve the doc object with id ="123" ? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: `_.each` is from Underscore.js, not from jQuery...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read up on how [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) handles break;

```
var object_with_id_123;
$.each(list, function(key, val){
  if (val.doc.id == "123") {
    object_with_id_123 = val;
    return false; // break;
  }

  return true; // continue; - just to satisfy jsLint
});
console.log(object_with_id_123);
```

Answer (score 15):

Actually, [_.detect](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#detect) would be more a appropriate function to solve this problem:

```
var list = [
    {"doc":{"id": "123", "name":"abc"}},
    {"doc":{"id": "345", "name":"xyz"}},
    {"doc":{"id": "123", "name":"str"}}
];

_.detect(list, function (obj) {return obj.doc.id === "123"});
```

result:

```
{"doc":{"id": "123", "name":"abc"}}
```

---

Alternatively, if you'd like to return both objects with id = '123', then you could substitute _.detect with [_.select](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#select).

```
_.select(list, function (obj) {return obj.doc.id === "123"});
```

result:

```
[{"doc":{"id": "123", "name":"abc"}}, {"doc":{"id": "123", "name":"str"}}]
```

Comment: Great answer! Does the job perfectly!

Comment: What if you wanted the index instead of the object returned?

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = [{"doc":{"id": "123", "name":"abc"}}, {"doc":{"id": "345", "name":"xyz"}},{"doc":{"id": "123", "name":"str"}}]

var olist = [];
$.each(list,function(key, value){
    if(value.doc.id =="123"){
        olist.push(value);
    }

})

    $.each(olist,function(key, value){
                alert(JSON.stringify(value))


})
```

Answer (score 0):

because you have 2 results with id 123 i've added the array result. If you have 1 result, you could return obj.doc instead of adding it to result

```
var result = [];
$.each(list, function(index, obj) { 
    if(obj.doc.id == 123) {
        result.push(obj.doc);
    }
});
```